# Homotopy group of a path space.

Tags: homotopy-theory

I am studying now a homotopy theory and I have a question.

Suppose that we have a connected space $X$, and a $\pi_{1}(X)$ action on $\pi_{2}(X)$ is trivial.

In this case, is it true that

$\pi_{1}(\Omega X) \simeq \pi_{2}(X)$ ?

If it is true, is there a reference for this result?

If not, is there any relation?

Thank you.

Comment: This is always true, in fact. It should be proved in any good algebraic topology textbook.

Comment: ($\Omega X $ is called the *loop space* of $ X $; the path space is something else.

Comment: This is a special case of the adjunction between smash products and mapping spaces.